# angular-ui and datepicker directive error

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui

I am trying the following example/demo and I keep getting this error in my chrome console:

```
Error: Non-assignable model expression: undefined (directive: datepicker)
```

I dont get any 404s during the execution.

The code used is based on:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

or

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

The code in my modal template:

```
<pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>
    <div class="well well-small pull-left" ng-model="dt">
        <datepicker min="minDate" show-weeks="showWeeks"></datepicker>
    </div>
```

The code in modal controller:

```
$scope.today = function () {
        $scope.dt = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.showWeeks = true;
    $scope.toggleWeeks = function () {
        $scope.showWeeks = !$scope.showWeeks;
    };

    $scope.toggleMin = function () {
        $scope.minDate = ($scope.minDate) ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleMin();

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        'year-format': "'yy'",
        'starting-day': 1
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to define the ng-model in the datepicker:

```
<div class="well well-small pull-left" >
        <datepicker min="minDate" show-weeks="showWeeks" ng-model="dt"></datepicker>
    </div>
```